# Theming the top app bar and contextual action bar with custom colors not working in Material 3 It is a bug?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-theme, material3

### Update

After I created a new project with a Material 3 theme and I tried to change the top app bar and contextual action bar I can confirm it's a bug, I've opened [issue here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/249434847) please star it or vote +1 to pay attention to it and solve it as soon as possible

### Theming the top app bar

I followed the instruction in [this link](https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/implementation)
to apply a custom theme on all toolbar and contextual action bar in my app, but it's not working at all it's always be white color on light mode and dark in night mode, tested on material version implementation the following versions

`implementation ('com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1')` and
`implementation ('com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0-alpha01')` android 11 and above

let's start with my colors light version

```
<color name="primaryColor">#1aae66</color>
<color name="primaryLightColor">#5ee194</color>
<color name="primaryDarkColor">#007d3a</color>

<color name="secondaryColor">#1de9b6</color>
<color name="secondaryLightColor">#6effe8</color>
<color name="secondaryDarkColor">#00b686</color>

<color name="primaryTextColor">@color/white</color>
<color name="secondaryTextColor">#000000</color>
```

colors night

```
 <color name="primaryColor" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">@color/darker</color>
    <color name="primaryLightColor" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">@color/darkGray</color>
    <color name="primaryDarkColor" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">@color/black</color>

    <color name="secondaryColor" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">#4db6ac</color>
    <color name="secondaryLightColor" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">#82e9de</color>
    <color name="secondaryDarkColor" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">#00867d</color>
```

**theme.xml (light version)**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.DummyAppKotlin" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/secondaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/secondaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/secondaryTextColor</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.App.Toolbar</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/contextualActionBarColor</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.Material3.Dark.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationTransition</item>
        <item name="popupMenuBackground">@color/primaryColor</item>

    </style>

    <style name="Widget.App.Toolbar" parent="Widget.Material3.Toolbar">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Toolbar</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.Material3.Dark.ActionBar</item>


    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Toolbar" parent="">
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
    </style>
```

**theme.xml (night version)**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.DummyAppKotlin" parent="Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/secondaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/secondaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/secondaryTextColor</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.App.Toolbar</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/contextualActionBarColor</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.Material3.Dark.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationTransition</item>
        <item name="popupMenuBackground">@color/primaryColor</item>

    </style>

    <style name="Widget.App.Toolbar" parent="Widget.Material3.Toolbar">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Toolbar</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.Material3.Dark.ActionBar</item>


    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Toolbar" parent="">
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
    </style>
```

There is only one way that works to change the toolbar color, is to set my custom theme to **AppBarLayout** the attribute  `style="@style/Widget.App.Toolbar"` is ignored in toolbar and applied with **AppBarLayout**

here's example

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:liftOnScroll="true">

             <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                style="@style/Widget.App.Toolbar" =============> This won't work
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                app:title="Post details" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

### The Second Problem

in Contextual Action Mode/Bar was when I tried to override its colors with the attributes **actionModeBackground**

`<item name="actionModeBackground">@color/contextualActionBarColor</item>`

it should be my dark black color but it's notworking/ignored, the other attribute **actionModeTheme** with  `<item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.Material3.Dark.ActionBar</item>` it uses the main primary color green for action bar

### This example of the contextual action bar of (material 3)

[image]

### This example of the contextual action bar of (material 2) before I updated to material 3

[image]

Comment: Hello. Did you manage to fix it? Is it still a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the bug and tried to create new project to confirm it, it's seems google ignored the material android section, anyway if you need to work with material 3 you can use `style="@style/Widget.App.Toolbar"` and put it into `AppBarLayout` and make the other theme for contextual action bar, other suggest is to keep tour app in material 2 untill this bug is fixed

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I'll keep the app with material 2 until this bug is fixed

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This answer targets the second problem (Contextual Action)

> in Contextual Action Mode/Bar was when I tried to override its colors
> with the attributes `actionModeBackground`
>
> ```
> name="actionModeBackground">@color/contextualActionBarColor</item>
> ```
>
> it should be my dark black color but it's notworking/ignored, the
> other attribute actionModeTheme with  `<item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.Material3.Dark.ActionBar</item>`
>
> it uses the main primary color green for action bar

You can use the [`actionModeStyle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#actionModeStyle) style attribute to set a custom style to the Action Mode,

To change the background use the `background` attribute:

```
<style name="Theme.DummyAppKotlin" parent="Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/action_mode_style</item>    

</style>

<style name="action_mode_style" parent="@style/Widget.Material3.ActionMode">
    <item name="background">@color/contextualActionBarColor</item>
</style>
```